# Showing only private methods with Sphinx' Autodoc

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

There are several questions here about showing private methods using Autodoc, but I've not seen anything about showing *only* private methods.

Private methods and regular methods can be shown as follows:

```
.. autoclass:: my_package.my_file.MyClass
   :members:
   :private-members:
```

However, removing `:members:` causes *none* of the methods to be displayed.

How can I show just the private methods, and just for this one directive?

Comment: would make much more sens that :private-members: just add the :private-members:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way!

Using the [Skipping Members](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#skipping-members) setting detailed here, I was able to define a rule to selectively skip members.

In conf.py:

```py
def hide_non_private(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    # if private-members is set, show only private members
    if 'private-members' in options and not name.startswith('_'):
        # skip public methods
        return True
    else:
        # do not modify skip - private methods will be shown
        return None

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', hide_non_private)
```

Whenever autodoc has to decide whether or not to include a member in documentation (which it does whenever a the subject of a directive contains that member), this function is called. The function returns a bool representing whether or not this member should be skipped. If `True`, it doesn't appear. If `False`, it does. If `None`, then the result of this function is ignored and the next skip-checking method is called.

If the directive contains the option `:private-members:` and the member name does not start with `_` (i.e. it's a public method), it is skipped and will not appear on the documentation.

So when I generate documentation using:

```
.. autoclass:: my_package.my_file.MyClass
   :members:
   :private-members:
```

The public methods are not shown, and the private methods are.

I still need to set `:members:`, though, otherwise this check doesn't even happen in the first place. If I find somewhere where I do actually need to list both public and private methods, I'll need to find some more sophisticated check.